# Assistance on simple regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

What is the correct regex for extracting the resultCount given the following pattern (note I don't care about anything else in the string):

```
{
 "resultCount":12,
 "results": [blah blah..
```

Here is the regex I tried.. but no dice (i.e no match..) ..

```
.*resultCount":([\d]+),.*
```

Language is java; and this DOES matter (turns out the regex expression works fine in vanilla regex).  So i'm going to see if some character like quote is the problem

Comment: That doesn't look too wrong, although the square brackets aren't necessary. Two things though: which language are you using this in? Your input looks suspicously like JSON. Wouldn't it be easier/more reliable/more readable to use a JSON parser?

Comment: Why not just forget about those `.*` (or are your regexes anchored to string start and end)? In some regexp flavours, the dot might not even match that linebreak…

Comment: @buettner.  Yes you are right about language being important: this regex works fine but not in java.  I don't want full blown json parser in this context.

Comment: @Bergi: you are also on right track.  answer is to add DOTALL,

Comment: @javadba the proper solution is to remove both `.*` (and the trailing comma if you like) and use `find` instead of `matches` (as the former doesn't require the entire string to be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using the `String.matches` function in Java which requires the entire string to be matched by the pattern (which is why you included `.*` before and after the pattern). As Bergi correctly spotted, the `.` will generally not match the line breaks, so you cannot get a full-string match without using `DOTALL`.

But that is really a bit of a hack. You are not actually interested in matching the whole string (that is something you do for validation). And Java provides a second method of pattern matching, which takes a bit more code, but allows you to do the job properly (finding substring matches - and multiple of them if needed). Here is some quick sample code with a fixed pattern (assuming `str` is your input string):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("resultCount\":\\s*(\\d+)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Both `Pattern` and `Matcher` are part of `java.util.regex`. Code based [on this tutorial page](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regexjava).

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/x0LueV)

Of course the inclusion of `\\s*` in the pattern is up to you, but it's definitely something that could happen if you don't generate the JSON yourself, and it can't do any harm, since there's no overlap with `\\d`.

Comment: Hi, I actually have both use cases (match and find) and already employ both code fragments in my regex utils.  But i'll go ahead and mark your response as accepted.